# make multiple REST API calls parallel in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My API does the POST request for registration ,to find the duplicate records in the request body it does 4 GET calls to other API.

1. Checks mobile number already exists or not
2. Email ID already exists or not
3. Check for other 2 unique IDs already exists or not.

Code:

```
if(mobile!=null){
   if(checkDuplicateMobileNo(mobile)){ // restTemplate call to GET API
     throw new BadRequestException();
}

if(email!=null){
   if(checkDuplicateEmail(email)){ // restTemplate call to GET API
     throw new BadRequestException();
}

if(uniqueId1!=null){
   if(checkDuplicateUniqueId1(uniqueId1)){ // restTemplate call to GET API
     throw new BadRequestException();
}

if(uniqueId2!=null){
   if(checkDuplicateUniqueId1(uniqueId1)){ // restTemplate call to GET API
     throw new BadRequestException();
}
```

// then do post request

How can I do duplicate checks parallelly in Spring?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java's CompletableFuture :

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

if (mobile != null) {
   futures.add(checkDuplicateMobileNo(mobile).thenAccept(duplicateExists -> {
   if (duplicateExists) {
       throw new BadRequestException();
   }
   }));
}

if (email != null) {
    futures.add(checkDuplicateEmail(email).thenAccept(duplicateExists -> {
   if (duplicateExists) {
       throw new BadRequestException();
   }
   }));
}

if (uniqueId1 != null) {
    futures.add(checkDuplicateUniqueId1(uniqueId1).thenAccept(duplicateExists -> {
   if (duplicateExists) {
       throw new BadRequestException();
   }
   }));
}

if (uniqueId2 != null) {
   futures.add(checkDuplicateUniqueId2(uniqueId2).thenAccept(duplicateExists -> {
   if (duplicateExists) {
       throw new BadRequestException();
   }
   }));
}

CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();

// then do post request
```

Yes, if you write the duplicate checks using if statements, they will be executed in sequence, one after another. This means that the next check will only be performed after the previous one has completed. This can cause delays and slow down the overall execution of your code.

To make the duplicate checks execute in parallel:

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

if(mobile!=null){
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
  if(checkDuplicateMobileNo(mobile)){
     throw new BadRequestException();
  }
   }));
}

if(email!=null){
   futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
  if(checkDuplicateEmail(email)){
     throw new BadRequestException();
  }
   }));
}

if(uniqueId1!=null){
   futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
  if(checkDuplicateUniqueId1(uniqueId1)){
     throw new BadRequestException();
  }
   }));
}

if(uniqueId2!=null){
   futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
  if(checkDuplicateUniqueId2(uniqueId2)){
     throw new BadRequestException();
  }
   }));
}

CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();

// then do post request
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! will it not go in sequence by going through all the if conditions? And can we use @async?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to comprehend your question as to what exactly you want to achieve. But with the initial understanding, I believe you can do the following.

1. Make your client reactive (i.e. use `WebClient` instead of `RestTemplate`)
2. Do **NOT** `block` the response of the client call immediately (i.e. you will have a `Mono` as a return)
3. Make all 4 client calls within a `Mono.zip`
4. Perform your computation and registration
5. `blockOptional` to complete the flow.

Hope this gives a baseline.

If unclear, feel free to add a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  due to inbuilt framework I have to continue with RestTemplate. So checking the good solution for based on it.

Comment: could you please provide some examples.... When I try Mono.zip the exchange method is deprecated

Comment: You could probably use `retrieve()` instead. Assuming all your `checkDuplicateXXX` methods use webClient and return a `Mono`. In the calling method, you can do something like 

`Mono.zip(checkDuplicateMobile(), checkDupicateEmail(), ...).map(tuple -> DO_COMPUTATION).block()`

So your clients are async and you are doing computation once all responses are available and the result returned from the async flow by `block()`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How can we make parameters dynamic to Mono.zip(..). Say if my Mobile no. is null I don't want to check duplicate..it should be Mono.zip(checkDupicateEmail(),checkDupicateSomethingElse(),..)

Comment: I have added this way...
-----------------------------------
public Mono<Optional<Mobile>> getByMobile(Map<String, String> queryParamHuman) {
        if(queryParamHuman.get(Constants.MOBILE) != null){
            return webClient.get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder ->uriBuilder.path(url)).build())
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(PingDigitalIdentityGetResponse.class).map(Optional::of).defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());
        }
        return Mono.<Mobile>empty().map(Optional::of).defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());
    }

Comment: I would rather keep the `null` check within the validator method and still call it. the validator method will in itself check duplicates after checking if it's NOT `null`. If it's `null` you can return `Mono.empty()`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, will implement accordingly :)

Comment: Hi @Dishant, can we do non blocking here instead of Mono.zip(checkDuplicateMobile(), checkDupicateEmail(), ...).map(tuple -> DO_COMPUTATION).block(). As it will wait for all the responses